# Drag and drop file upload IE9, IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I need to implement drag and drop file upload on my application. I could upload the files using all browsers except lower versions of **IE9**. The drag and drop file upload is not working on browsers **IE9**, **IE8** and **IE7**. Can you please help me to Implement the drag and drop file upload in all browsers including **IE9**, **IE8** and **IE7**?

Please find my code below:

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(document).on('drop', 'body', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.originalEvent == null || e.originalEvent == undefined) {
          var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
          console.log(file);
        } else {


          var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]; // I have the file.. now what? 
          console.log(file);
        }
      });

      $("body").on("dragenter dragover", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="holder">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Drop files here
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul id="fileList">
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <hr />
</body>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but this was the exact reason I pushed the decision _not_ to support those old browsers anymore when I ran into this a year ago (of course we based it on security reasons). IE10 is more than five years old by now, IE9 went out of support with the end of Vista. How long do people expect support on antique software?

Comment: What exactly is not happening? What part of your code isn't running? Have you debugged it at all to see where it's stopping?

Comment: You're using `jquery-2.2.4.min.js`. See this link: https://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/.

Comment: On the drop event file details is not getting on IE 9

Comment: I using same version that you have mentioned `jquery-2.2.4.min.js`

Comment: @Vijeeshkumarvofox `jQuery 2.*` does not support older browsers such as IE6, IE7, IE8.

Comment: Jquery events are working, but the properties is used for getting file details is not working (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0])

Comment: MDN [claims `DataTransfer` support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#Browser_compatibility) is only in IE10 upwards.  You're simply trying to use things that didn't exist in the timelines of those browser versions.